# How to send form data in ReactNative web view?

Tags: react-native, webview

I want to send form data values to my webview url before it loaded. I'm getting this values from redux.

This is what I tried. But It's not working

```
    let token=this.props.usersData ? this.props.usersData.token : null
    let currencyValue=this.props.usersData ? this.props.usersData.currencyValue :null
    let paymentValue=this.props.usersData ? this.props.usersData.paymentValue : null

    let formdata = new FormData();

    formdata.append("token", token)
    formdata.append("currencyValue", currencyValue)
    formdata.append("paymentValue", paymentValue)

    return (
        <WebView
            style={styles.webView}
            scrollEnabled={true}
            source=
            {{uri: 'https://myweb.com/tokenization?type=datasave&test=yes', 
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', body:formdata }}}

        />

    );
```

Please note that props values are getting without any issue (no null values there)

Answer (score 0):

You must use `injectedJavaScript` and pass a string, try this:

```
return (
    <WebView
        style={styles.webView}
        scrollEnabled={true}
        source={{ uri: 'https://myweb.com/tokenization?type=datasave&test=yes' }}    
        injectedJavaScript={`window.token=${token}; window.currencyValue={currencyValue}; window.paymentValue=${paymentValue}`}
    />

);
```

then in your myweb.com you can get this variables with `window.token`, `window.currencyValue`, `window.paymentValue`

Comment: @apple_92 can you explain yourself better?